# Post variables in ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

I am getting user movie interst and posting it to another page using ajax requst as below. I want to send some other variables along with existing var `a`.

```
FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) {
    console.log(mydata.email);
    console.log(mydata.id); 
    var myid=mydata.id;
    var name=mydata.name;
    var email=mydata.email; 
    var imgpath="https://graph.facebook.com/"+myid+"/picture?type=small";
    // I want to send myid,name,email with a in below code. How can I do and receive it on movies_db.php?

    $.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a},function(data){
        $.ajax({
            url:'url.php'
                ,async:     true
                ,cache:     false
                ,dataType:  'html'
                ,success:   function(data){
                $('body').html(data);
                FB.XFBML.parse();
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to send myid,name,email with a in below code. How can I do and receive it on movies_db.php?

Comment: Have you looked at this? [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass as many key/value pairs as you want

```
$.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':a, name: name, email: email, parameter_name: value}, ...
```

In your PHP - movies_db.php

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$other = $_POST['parameter_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
FB.api('/me?fields=movies,email', function(mydata) {
    console.log(mydata.email);
    console.log(mydata.id); 
    var myid=mydata.id;
    var name=mydata.name;
    var email=mydata.email; 
    var imgpath="https://graph.facebook.com/"+myid+"/picture?type=small";
    // I want to send myid,name,email with a in below code. How can I do and receive it on movies_db.php?

    $.post('movies_db.php',{'myd':myid, 'name': name, 'email': email},function(data){
        $.ajax({
            url:'url.php'
                ,async:     true
                ,cache:     false
                ,dataType:  'html'
                ,success:   function(data){
                $('body').html(data);
                FB.XFBML.parse();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object from the data and post it to server.

```
 var myid=mydata.id;
 var name=mydata.name;
 var email=mydata.email; 
 var imgpath="https://graph.facebook.com/"+myid+"/picture?type=small";
 var inputdata = {}
 inputdata = {'myid': myid,
         'name' : name,
         'email' : email,
         'imgpath' : imgpath
        }


 // Use inputdata as post data here
 $.post('movies_db.php',inputdata,function(data){
        $.ajax({
            url:'url.php'
                ,async:     true
                ,cache:     false
                ,dataType:  'html'
                ,success:   function(data){
                $('body').html(data);
                FB.XFBML.parse();
            }
        });
    });
```

Now you can access POST data in your php file.